# Perspective Virtual Camera library issue Corona SDK

Tags: lua, camera, coronasdk, perspective

Hello all I am currently developing an application that I am going to use the perspective library with. I have imported the library and have written the correct code it seems but to no avail my camera is not working properly. I am attempting to get the camera to follow the main character you are moving around with the buttons. I added him and the background and a "tree" to the camera and set him as the focus but it still will not follow him. Here is my code please tell me what I have done wrong here and how to fix it.

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()
local perspective = require( "perspective" )
local camera = perspective.createView()
local physics = require( "physics" )
--physics.setDrawMode( "hybrid" )



local function start( event )
if( event.phase == "ended" ) then

end
end 

local bg
local floor
local leftwall
local rightwall
local player  
local button1
local button2
local pausebtn
local tree

local function b1( event )
if( event.phase == "ended" ) then
player:applyLinearImpulse( -.01, -.1 )
end
end

local function b2( event )
if( event.phase == "ended" ) then
player:applyLinearImpulse( .01, -.1 )
end
end

local function playerCollision( event )
if( event.phase == "began" ) then
storyboard.gotoScene( "gameover" )
end
end 

local function pause( event )
if( event.phase == "ended" ) then
storyboard.showOverlay( "pause" )
physics.pause()
end
end

function scene:createScene( event )
local group = self.view
    physics.start()



    bg = display.newImage( "bg.png", display.contentWidth/2, display.contentHeight/2, display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight )
camera:add(bg, 3, false)
    player = display.newImage( "player.png", display.contentWidth/2, display.contentHeight/2, display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight )
    player.collision = playerCollision  
camera:add(player, 1, true)
    tree = display.newImage( "tree.png", 200, 200)
camera:add(tree, 2, false)

    floor = display.newRect( 285, 375, 570, 1 )
    button1 = display.newImage( "button1.png", 50, 275 )
    button2 = display.newImage( "button2.png", 515, 275 )

    leftwall = display.newRect( 0, -1000, 1, 5000 )
    rightwall = display.newRect( 570, 300, 1, 5000 )

    pausebtn = display.newImage( "pausebtn.png", 540, 30 )

    -- Physics
    physics.addBody( player )

    physics.addBody( floor ) 
    floor.bodyType = "static"

    physics.addBody( rightwall )
    rightwall.bodyType = "static"

    physics.addBody( leftwall )
    leftwall.bodyType = "static"



    group:insert(bg)
    group:insert(player)
    group:insert(floor)
    group:insert(button1)
    group:insert(button2)
    group:insert(rightwall)
    group:insert(leftwall)
    group:insert(pausebtn) 
    group:insert(tree)

end

function scene:enterScene( event )
print( "game" )
button1:addEventListener( "touch", b1 )
button2:addEventListener( "touch", b2 )
player:addEventListener( "collision", playerCollision )
pausebtn:addEventListener( "touch", pause )



end

function scene:exitScene()

player = nil
camera:cancel()


end

function scene:destroyScene( event )



end 

scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )

scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )

scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )

scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )

return scene
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the call to `camera:track()` (which should probably go in the `enterScene` handler). You might also need `camera:setBounds(false)`.

If this still doesn't fix issue, remove all code from your post that is not required in order to duplicate the problem. If you can boil it down to a small example that I can run, I can try and post update.

Comment: I have added camera:track() to my code, but it is not working. I have tried it in both EnterScene and CreateScene, and camera:setBounds(false) does not fix the problem either